# Get default XML value in Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need set `android:scrollbarSize` back to the default value in `ScrollView`, because when I set  `android:scrollbarThumbVertical` to own color, `scrollbarSize` is automatically changed too much big size. Any side effect?.

I tried:

```
android:scrollbarSize="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
```

but size is the same big. If I try `android:scrollbarSize="4dp"`, size is the same as default, what I want. But I do not want to set hardcore size, due to different screen sizes layouts.

UPDATE:
Problem occurs only <= Android 7.1.1.

Comment: Add code from a template - https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browsed through the Android code and it seems they use an internal R file so I don't know if it's publicly available. This is from the config.xml file they use for the `ViewConfiguration.class` :

Java class:

```
mScrollbarSize = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
                com.android.internal.R.dimen.config_scrollbarSize);
```

XML

```
<!-- Default width of a vertical scrollbar and height of a horizontal scrollbar.
     Takes effect only if the scrollbar drawables have no intrinsic size. -->
<dimen name="config_scrollbarSize">4dp</dimen>
```

This is also a constant in `ViewConfiguration.java` :

```
/**
 * Defines the width of the horizontal scrollbar and the height of the vertical scrollbar in
 * dips
 */
private static final int SCROLL_BAR_SIZE = 4;
```

So yea best bet is to use 4dp. 4dp won't change in different screen sizes because they are Density Independent Pixels (Dip). That is the whole point. What you can do is create a new `dimens` resource file and add different values for different screen widths, so 4dp in phones and 8dp in tablets for example. [See here.](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)